# Alternative option for case condtion in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

How to check the column value zero or not

I want to insert 50 column values, each column i want to check whethere the value is 0 or not. If the value is 0 then it should be null

Query

```
insert into table1 values (Case when column1 = '0' then null else column1 end, .....
Case when column50 = '0' then null else column50 end)
```

The above query is working, but query length is too long because i am using the above query of 50 column's

there is any alternative option is there for check the column value is 0 or not.

like this `if(column1, 0) then null`

Need Query Help

Answer (score 4):

Try using [NULLIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx):

```
insert into table1 values (NULLIF(column1, '0'), .....
NULLIF(column50, '0'))
```

Comment: Very very interesting, I didn't know about NULLIF

Comment: i cannot able to save the string values, for example Nullif('" & column1 & "', '0') then result is 0 only, i am passing column1, column2 as a string.  ifnull will not work for string column values.....?

Comment: @Gopal: It should do - see the MSDN article linked in the answer.

Comment: if i am giving nullif(column1, '0') then it is working, if i am giving a as string,  a = column1, nullif('" & a & "', '0') then it is not working, it is saving as 0 instead of null, can you check please....